# Eclipse RCP icon in right bottom right to job progress bar

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

as it is stated in title, I write Eclipse RCP based application. I want to create icon in status area in right-bottom edge of the Eclipse RCP application. I would like to have this icon on very right side, so job progress bar will be on it's left side. Eclipse allows it, so I was able to move one toolbar manually to achieve that goal (I've highlighted this toolbar with the green border):

[image]

How Can I achieve such a result from the code? Are there any extension points that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to find solution for my problem. I was looking for:

```
<menuContribution
     allPopups="false"
     locationURI="toolbar:status.right">...</menuContribution>
```

with `locationURI="toolbar:status.right"` I was able to achieve my goal. Maybe someone will take benefits from this thread.